# Efficiently Loop Through Millions of Elements

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of 262144 elements in a list created through "itertools.product". Now I have to loop over these elements and multiply it with all other elements, which is taking too much time. (I don't have any issue of memory / cpu)

```
    elements = []
    for e in itertools.product(range(4), repeat=9):
        elements.append(e)

    for row in elements:
       for col in elements:
          do_calculations(row, col)

    def do_calculations(ro, co):
        t = {}
        t[0] = [multiply(c=ro[0], r=co[0])]
        for i in range(1, len(ro)):
            _t = []
            for j in range(i+1):
                _t.append(multiply(c=ro[j], r=co[i-j]))
            t[i] = _t

            for vals in t.values():
                nx = len(vals)
                _co = ro[nx:]
                _ro = co[nx:]
                for k in range(len(_ro)):
                    vals.append(multiply(c=_co[k], r=_ro[k]))

            _t = []
            for k in t.values():
                s = k[0]
                for j in range(1, len(k)):
                    s = addition(c=s, r=k[j])
                _t.append(s)
        return _t

    def addition(c, r) -> int:
        __a = [[0, 3, 1, 2],
               [3, 2, 0, 1],
               [0, 3, 2, 1],
               [1, 0, 2, 3]]

        return __a[c][r]


    def multiply(c, r) -> int:
        __m = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 2, 3],
               [0, 3, 1, 2],
               [0, 2, 3, 1]]

        return __m[c][r]
```

it is taking too much time to process single col with rows....
can any one help me in this?
regards

Comment: You have to perform 262,144^2=68,719,476,736 multiplications? That's going to take a long time. Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @jwilson actually i have to make a grid of row/col and do some multiplication on row, col (which takes less than second)

Comment: One row will take 0.033 seconds * 262,144 = 8650 seconds = 144 minutes = 2.4 hours.

Comment: that is why I am asking about an efficient way @SergeyGlotov

Comment: Can you do your calculations with numpy?

Comment: If you can elaborate on what `doing_some_calculations` does, we might be able to find a way to vectorize this whole thing. Otherwise look into the [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) package and wrap your slow loop in their `@jit` decorator.

Comment: The looping isn't what's taking time, the calculations are. If a single invocation of your function takes 0.033 seconds, doing it 262k times will be 2.4 hours, and repeating that for 262k rows will take about 71 _years_. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Without knowing the goal this is impossible to answer.

Comment: `
def mul(ro, co):
    t = {}
    t[0] = [multiply(c=ro[0], r=co[0])]
    for i in range(1, len(ro)):
        _t = []
        for j in range(i+1):
            _t.append(multiply(c=ro[j], r=co[i-j]))
        t[i] = _t

    for vals in t.values():
        nx = len(vals)
        _co = ro[nx:]
        _ro = co[nx:]
        for k in range(len(_ro)):
            vals.append(multiply(c=_co[k], r=_ro[k]))

    _t = []
    for k in t.values():
        s = k[0]
        for j in range(1, len(k)):
            s = addition(c=s, r=k[j])
        _t.append(s)
    return _t
`

Comment: multiply/addition are function which uses 4x4 multidimensional list to extract the result

Comment: @ابوصفا Please [edit] the body of your question including the code that you posted as a comment. I'd do it myself but the indentation (and consequently the program flow) has to be guessed because your code is, ehm, _inscrutable_.  While you are at it, could you please give us the definitions of `multiply` and `addition`,  otherwise it could be very difficult to help you?  — that said it looks like your code could be streamlined using Numpy.

Comment: can you please guide how to write code in comment box, as i try both ``` and single ` but it doesn't work....

Comment: ```
def addition(c, r) -> int:
    __a = [[0, 3, 1, 2],
           [3, 2, 0, 1],
           [0, 3, 2, 1],
           [1, 0, 2, 3]]

    return __a[c][r]


def multiply(c, r) -> int:
    __m = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 3, 1, 2],
           [0, 2, 3, 1]]

    return __m[c][r]
```

Comment: @gboffi i updated the original question with full code, thanks

Comment: anyone please ????

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a python guy but

1. make sure col is a higher number than row ([small optimization, but optimization nevertheless](https://hackernoon.com/neat-optimization-trick-reduce-the-number-of-jumps-in-a-nested-loop-a97fdbfd4c2b))
2. use a multiprocessing library ([alink](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Parallelising-Python-with-Threading-and-Multiprocessing)). that should cut the calculation time.

   (as noted in comment by @Skam, multithreading does not increase performance in such case)

also, you might consider some optimizations in the calculation itself.

Comment: Python threading isn't traditional threading. Only one Python thread can use the interpreter at a time due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). (Note, that a single Python thread can spawn multiple C threads getting a more true concurrency)
As a result, threading is really only good for I/O bound operations, not CPU bound like it is in this case.
Multiprocessing would be the correct way to do divide and conquer CPU bound work in Python.

Comment: @Skam yes, you are absolutely correct. Will change the answer.